# Resume code in try block after exception is caught

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am fairly new to using try/catch blocks, so I don't know how exactly to perform this command.

If I catch an error, I would like to wait a period of time(10 seconds or so) then try to run the same line of code to attempt to continue in my try block. My program is written in Java. I have looked at both these pages: [Page1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271911/php-is-it-possible-to-resume-the-try-block-after-the-exception-is-caught), [Page2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290356/need-to-resume-try-after-catch-block), but neither of them are in Java. I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544871/how-to-resume-code-even-after-exception-handling-with-try-and-catch-in-java?rq=1), but they are not solving in the using the catch block. Is this possible to do, and how would I implement this in my catch block instead of just printing the error?

Comment: Look at Thread.sleep(), you can easily throw that in a loop which'll suspend the execution of each loop iteration.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII The program essentially runs continuously, and errors maybe once every 24 hours. Although there have been primarily 2 lines causing the error, this would add a large amount of time to the program. Do you think this would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Haven't you attempted to fix what's causing the exception?

Comment: Not all exceptions are caused by bugs or programming faults. Consider SqlExceptions. You can't *fix* them.

Comment: @Connor You can enforce the sleep condition in the catch block whilst having the try block in the loop. Several examples exists below. That way the sleep will only occur when the exception is thrown. Ok, since it's two lines of code causing the issue, I'll throw up a bit of code that should do it. If I understand the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

99% of time, you want to re-run a code-block after a `try-catch` and not the line with exception.

If you need to run from that line, than that is an indication for you to take your code in another method that encapsulates only that code (maybe move the `try-catch` there too).

What i would advice is something like this:

```
void method(){
    try{
       codeline1;
       codeline2;
       codeline3;
       codeline4;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        restorClassStateBeforeCodeLine1();
        method();
    }
}
```

By that snipped i propose to have your entire `try-catch` in a separate method.

Waiting random intervals is bad practice also. You never know if 10 seconds is right every time or at all.

Another way that I advise against would be:

```
label: {
    try {
        ...
        if (condition)
            break label;
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It uses [java labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) to retry that part. I never tried but the `break` could be moved in the `catch` and the label in the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to return to a certain line in your try-block from inside a catch-block. Because when the `throw`is executed, the runtime system is going to pop frames from the call stack, looking for an exception handler to match the thrown exception and once the frame is popped from the stack, it's gone. More info about this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

What you can do is call the method that caused the `throw` from within the catch-block. But that means it is going to execute your method from the beginning, so maybe you want to try to rearrange your code so that this does not cause any other problems. EDIT: The other answer demonstrates exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This simple program loops through array values, testing each until it finds a value that doesn't generate an exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array=new int[]{0,0,0,0,5};
    for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)  {
        try {
            System.out.println(10/array[i]);
            break;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch(Exception ignore){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question ? I don't understand. No offence.

Comment: @Andrei it executes a line of code. If the code generates an exception, it waits a second, then retries the line of code. Otherwise, it continues. Is that not what was asked?

Comment: More or less. From what I understood he requested an answer for the case where there are more lines of code in the try.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
   try{
      //actions where some exception can be thrown
      break;//executed when no exceptions appeared only
   }
   catch(YourException e){
      Thread.sleep(10_000);
   }
}
```

This cycle will be repeated while you instructions haven't executed. When code in try-block executed succesfully break helps you leave this cycle

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that it is only 2 lines of code that you experience the intermittent error with, try something similar to this.

```
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Some Logic

            //Error throwing logic in method
            while(!doLogic())
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);//Sleep here or in doLogic catch
            }

        //Continuing other logic!
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static Integer i = null;
    public static boolean doLogic()
    {
        try
        {
            //Lines that throw error
            System.out.println(i.toString());//NPE First run
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            i = 1;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```